Объект без типа в строгом/не строгом режиме
Пример со строгим режимом без типа


"use strict";
user = {
  name: 'elem',
  age: 21
}

console.log(user) // user is not defined



Пример без строгого режима без типа


user = {
  name: 'elem',
  age: 21
}

console.log(user) // { name: 'elem', age: 21 }



Пример со строгим режимом в цикле с типом var


"use strict";

for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  var user = {
    name: 'elem',
    age: 21
  }
}

console.log(user) // { name: 'elem', age: 21 }



Пример без строгого режима в цикле без типа


for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
  user = {
    name: 'elem',
    age: 21
  }
}

console.log(user) // { name: 'elem', age: 21 }



Вопрос: Можно ли сказать, что если не указывать тип у объекта, то он будет глобальным (var)?

Ты путаешь "объявление" переменной (var, let, const) с "типом"... Так же ты не понимаешь как работает var. Более подробно тут https://doka.guide/js/var-let/

И непонятно откуда первый пример. Вообще-то в строгом режиме должна быть ошибка ReferenceError: ...

@ksa насчёт объявления и типом, да, я согласен, я перепутал, но что я не понимаю в работе с var? Я переходил по ссылке, и всё, что там было написано я уже знал

Если бы ты все понимал - твоего вопроса не было бы... Начну с того что нужно таки объявлять переменные. Но если ты написал какой-то левый скриптик на странице и не объявил переменную - она становится глобальной.

Для ясности попробуй запустить с разные данными объекты для каждого случая

он будет глобальным (var)? объявление с помощью var не делает переменную глобальной. ;)

@kas Вы имеете в виду, что если var создан в функции? Если он создан в функции, то обратиться к нему за пределами функции не получится. Про то что нужно объявлять переменные (как минимум для понимания) я знаю, я просто решил спросить про то, что если не использовать let, const и var. Ну а за последнее: "Но если ты написал какой-то левый скриптик на странице и не объявил переменную - она становится глобальной." Я про это и хотел узнать.
